Why isn't the isAuthenticated$ observable always emitting the value false even if the user is logged in?
My idea is that once I log in, it is redirected to a route that I already have created in my router module, I have reviewed everything, and I can log in and log out, but nevertheless the state of the observable is always false. How could I make the observable work correctly?
This is my log component
 ``` import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
// import {FormControl, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms'

import { AuthService } from '@auth0/auth0-angular';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { MatInput } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatFormField, MatLabel } from '@angular/material/form-field';
@Component({
    selector: 'login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrl: './login.component.scss',
    standalone: true,
    imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, MatFormField, MatLabel, MatInput]
})
export class LoginComponent  implements  OnInit {
  
  formularioUsuario!:FormGroup;//form group lo uso para obtener los valores de los input dell formulario
  
  // email = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]);//validators required  es para que el campo se obliatorio
  // mensajeError:string = '';//mensaje que se mostrara al haber un error al introducir el email
  constructor(public formulario:FormBuilder,public auth: AuthService, private router:Router){//form builder es para  generar controles(esto es cada elemento de un formulario, input, select)
    console.log("test")
   
    this.formularioUsuario=this.formulario.group({
       email:[''],
       password:['']
    }

    )
    

  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    
       this.auth.isAuthenticated$.subscribe(isAuthenticated=>{
      console.log("test");
      console.log(isAuthenticated,'valor');
      if(isAuthenticated){
        console.log('usuaario ya logeado redirijiendoa')
        this.router.navigate(['/champions'])//si esta logueado redirijo al usuariio a la pagina de campeones de forma provisional
      
      }
    })//Es un obserbable que verifica si el usuario esta logeado es decur devyekve un  boleean true false
    
  } ```

This is my main.ts
```   import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';


import { importProvidersFrom } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app/app-routing.module';
import { BrowserModule, bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { provideAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-angular';
import { provideAnimationsAsync } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations/async';
import { provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'; 


bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
    providers: [
        importProvidersFrom(BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule),
        provideAnimationsAsync(),
        provideHttpClient(), 
        provideAuth0({
            domain: '',
            clientId: '',
            authorizationParams: {
                redirect_uri: window.location.origin
            }
        })
    ]
})
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
 ``` 

And  this is the login.component.html
``` <form (ngSubmit)="enviarUsuario()" [formGroup]="formularioUsuario"><!--se activa al hacer el submit-->
    <div>
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Introduce tu correo</mat-label>
            <input matInput type="email" required formControlName="email">
            <!-- @if (email.invalid) {
              <mat-error>{{mensajeError}}</mat-error>
            } -->
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div>
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Introduce tu contraseña</mat-label>
            <input matInput type="password" required formControlName="password">
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Iniciar sesión"  (click)="auth.loginWithRedirect()">
    <input type="reset" value="Cancelar">
</form> ```

